# Rearranging a double sum

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, summation

Given is the double sum

$$\sum_{i = 0}^N {N\choose i}\alpha_i\sum_{j=0}^{N-i} {{N-i}\choose j}v^{(N-i-j)}u^{(j)}$$

where $$v^{(m)}$$ is the m-th derivative (single variable). I'd like to rearrange the first expression and arrive at

$$\sum_{l = 0}^N \beta_l v^{(l)}$$
The 'betas' can be anything that comes out from reworking the first expression. I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $l=N-i-j$, and thus $j=N-i-l$, you have

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
\sum_{i = 0}^N {N\choose i}\alpha_i\sum_{j=0}^{N-i} {{N-i}\choose j}v^{(N-i-j)}u^{(j)}\\&=&
\sum_{i = 0}^N\sum_{j=0}^{N-i} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose j}v^{(N-i-j)}u^{(j)}
\\&=&
\sum_{i = 0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{N-i} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose N-i-l}v^{(l)}u^{(N-i-l)}
\\&=&
\sum_{i = 0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{N-i} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose l}v^{(l)}u^{(N-i-l)}
\\&=&
\sum_{l = 0}^N\sum_{i=0}^{N-l} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose l}v^{(l)}u^{(N-i-l)}
\\&=&
\sum_{l = 0}^Nv^{(l)}\sum_{i=0}^{N-l} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose l}u^{(N-i-l)}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

so

$$
\beta_l=\sum_{i=0}^{N-l} {N\choose i}\alpha_i {{N-i}\choose l}u^{(N-i-l)}\;.
$$

There's a general pattern here that you can apply in transforming double sums of products: Pull the double sum to the front, relabel the indices (if required), switch the sums, and pull the factors independent of the second summation index in front of the second sum.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you... Could you only explain on row 4 why ${N-i \choose N-i-l}$ is identical with ${N-i \choose l}$. Also, on row 5 how $$\sum_{i = 0}^N\sum_{l=0}^{N-i}$$ becomes $$\sum_{l = 0}^N\sum_{i=0}^{N-l}$$

Comment: @user142523: First question: $\binom mk=\binom m{m-k}$ is a fundamental symmetry of the binomial coefficients. Combinatorially speaking: There are as many ways to choose $k$-element subsets from an $m$-element set as there are to choose their $(m-k)$-element complements. Second question: Draw the triangle of points in the $(i,l)$-plane that the first double sum covers and express it in rows instead of columns. In particular, you can rearrange the limit that defines the hypothenuse of that triangle, $l\le N-i$, as $i\le N-l$.

Comment: Wow, amazing. The triangle really helped me see all the $(i,l)$ pairs and then the change in the sum is clear to understand. Thank you!